# Getting 403 from Apache served static files, even though I have read/write permissions - Django

Tags: django, apache, static, http-status-code-403, django-staticfiles

I have a Django application that I have deployed, and all has been well until last night. When I try to run my live site, via webfaction, I get a bunch of 403 forbidden response codes for my static files. I have a symbolic link to a static directory on the top level of my project, and the STATIC_ROOT in my settings configuration is correct. I also checked the permissions of one of the files that is giving me an issue, and it says I have at least read/write permissions.

[image]

[image]

But I'm still getting a 403, and am not sure why since it has been working fine for months. The apache config is all correct too, and the site is running smoothly. It is just the static resources.

apache/conf/httpd.conf

```
ServerRoot "/home/abenton42/webapps/arkansastherapistconnection/apache2"

LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule dir_module        modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule env_module        modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule mime_module       modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule rewrite_module    modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule setenvif_module   modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule wsgi_module       modules/mod_wsgi.so
LoadModule unixd_module      modules/mod_unixd.so

LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
CustomLog /home/abenton42/logs/user/access_arkansastherapistconnection.log combined
ErrorLog /home/abenton42/logs/user/error_arkansastherapistconnection.log

Listen 20377
KeepAlive Off
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-SSL on HTTPS=1
ServerLimit 1
StartServers 1
MaxRequestWorkers 5
MinSpareThreads 1
MaxSpareThreads 3
ThreadsPerChild 5

WSGIDaemonProcess arkansastherapistconnection processes=2 threads=12 python-path=/home/abenton42/webapps/arkansastherapistconnection:/home/abenton42/webapps/arkansastherapistconnection/a$
WSGIProcessGroup arkansastherapistconnection
WSGIRestrictEmbedded On
WSGILazyInitialization On
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/abenton42/webapps/arkansastherapistconnection/arkansas-therapist-connection/wsgi.py
```

I also checked the current user in linux with echo $USER, and the file permissions of my top level project directory. They are both 'abenton42'.

Comment: try to change `abenton42` to `www-data`, `chown www-data:www-data base.css`

Comment: Couldn't I do chown abenton42:abenton42 base.css ?

Comment: you have to change the owner then apache can access to your static file.

Comment: I'm getting an 'Invalid User www-data' message for both chown www-data:www-data base.css and chown www-data base.css

Comment: try to do like in this post http://askubuntu.com/questions/365087/grant-a-user-permissions-on-www-data-owned-var-www

Comment: hmmm, not sure why this question received a down vote. I thought it was a pretty well formulated question with adequate prior investigation on my own part, but whatever.

Comment: I don't know, it was not me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I submitted a ticket to the site's host, webfaction, and it turns out the issue was on their end, `"There was an issue with permissions for our nginx server that was causing this. That has been resolved."`. 
So I guess when in doubt, submit a ticket : ).